# How to create azurerm_resourcegroup through terraform only when it does not exist in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want my terraform script to create the resource group only when it does not exist in Azure, otherwise it should skip the creation of resource group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can use [Terraform external](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/external/latest/docs/data-sources/data_source) to execute the CLI command to check if the resource group exists or not. And then use the result to determine whether the resource group will create. Here is an example:

**./main.tf**

```
provider "azurerm" {
    features {}
}

variable "group_name" {}

variable "location" {
    default = "East Asia"
}

data "external" "example" {
    program = ["/bin/bash","./script.sh"]

    query = {
        group_name = var.group_name
    }
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
    count = data.external.example.result.exists == "true" ? 0 : 1
    name = var.group_name
    location = var.location
}
```

**./script.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash 

eval "$(jq -r '@sh "GROUP_NAME=\(.group_name)"')"
result=$(az group exists -n $GROUP_NAME)

jq -n --arg exists "$result" '{"exists":$exists}'
```

Comment: Thanks Charles for your solution. This solution works for me but I was looking for a solution where we can check the resource group exists or not using the terraform function   or features. This solution has a dependency on azure cli. Is there any other way through which we can achieve this.

Comment: @parasmehta There is no terraform function you can use to check if the resource group exists when you want to the script always succeed. My answer is the only way you can achieve your purpose.

Comment: Ok. Thanks a lot for your help and time:).

Comment: @parasmehta Well, if it works for you please accept it.

Comment: sure @CharlesXu :)

Answer (score 1):

Terraform is declarative, not imperative. When using Terraform you shouldn't need to check for existing resources

to validate your tf script

```
terraform plan
```

and  to apply the tf script changes

```
terraform apply
```

This will validate the resources if it already exists and create if not

Comment: If the resource group exists, I don't want the terraform script execution to fail. I want the script to proceed with the creation of other resources in the script. Is there any way to achieve this.

Comment: @Sajeethara it doesn't work that way with resource groups. it errors out saying it already exists.